# play sound in older browsers with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am using a custom developed WEB CLIENT with many customisations, which I cannot share.

It has been developed more than 1 year ago and it runs using ADOBE AIR. The webkit used was SAFARI.

I am experiencing major problems with playing sounds using javascript/jquery commands.

For EG this function does not work:

> function playSound(soundFile){
>
> ```
>         soundHandle = document.getElementById('soundHandle');
>         soundHandle.src = soundFile;
>         soundHandle.play();
> ```
>
> }

```
Neither this
function playSound(soundFile){
              soundHandle = new Audio(soundFile);
              soundHandle.play();
        }
```

playSound('http://www.pathtosound.com/sound.mp3');

Does anybody know any universal and older for doing this using javascript or jquery?

I am trying to play sound when different links or images are clicked. My sounds are mp3/wav but I could convert them to something else if required.

Comment: … `bgsound`, Flash, Java. >_< But why not just fix your custom-developed client?

Comment: because I was not its developer, and I want to see if there is a way of  achieving what I want without changing the client